# Why did they insist in using the `extern` specifier in the examples below?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, linkage

[[basic.link]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#6) (my emphasiss):

> **The name of a function declared in block scope** and the name of a variable declared by a block scope extern declaration **have linkage**.
>   `...`

```
static void f();
static int i = 0;

void g() {
    extern void f(); // internal linkage
    int i; // #2 i has no linkage
    {
        extern void f(); // internal linkage  <--
        extern int i; // #3 external linkage
    }
}
```

[[basic.link]/7](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#7):
`...`

```
namespace X {
    void p() {
        q(); // error: q not yet declared
        extern void q(); // q is a member of namespace X  <--
    }
    void middle() {
        q(); // error: q not yet declared
    }
    void q() { /* ... */ } // definition of X::q
}
void q() { /* ... */ } // some other, unrelated q
```

The `extern`specifiers pointed by the arrows are not necessary, given the very first sentence in paragraph [basic.link]/6 highlighted in bold characters above.Or am I missing something?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour That only refers to the variables, not the functions.

Answer (score 1):

The `extern`s are there to *emphasize* the respective comments, pointing out that the `extern` has no effect in certain circumstances (due to the rules outlined in that paragraph).

In the first example, `f` has internal linkage *despite* being declared `extern`, because it was first declared `static` at namespace-scope.

In the second exmaple, `extern` has no effect on the declaration because `q` is also declared at namespace scope without it (and `X::q` takes precedence over `::q`).

Answer (score 1):

I think the examples stave off some plausible but wrong ideas one might otherwise come up with.

In paragraph 6 one might expect `f()` to have *external* linkage since that is what `extern` "normally" (i.e. at file scope) means, but it's actually *internal* linkage because of the `static` declaration further up.

In paragraph 7 someone might expect `extern void q();` to make `q()` available outside of (or in loose speech *external* to) `p()`, so it could be called in `middle()`, but that doesn't happen either.

Both would still be true without the `extern` keyword, but then it wouldn't be surprising to people expecting `extern` to mean something different.